# Move backward through history skipping the same page with different query string

Tags: javascript, browser-history

When I refresh a page or redirect to the same one using the same url, I can click in a button with "window.history.back();" code and go back to the previous page.

However, If the query string was changed, I just back to the same page when I try to move back.

Example 1:

> page1.html -> page2.html -> page2.html
>   -> [click back button] -> **page1.html**

Example 2:

> page1.html -> page2.html ->
>   page2.html?x=123 -> [click back
>   button] -> **page2.html**

What I want:

> page1.html -> page2.html ->
>   page2.html?x=123 -> [click back
>   button] -> **page1.html**

So, the question is, Can I check if the page is the same using JavaScript to ignore query string changes and move back to the real previous page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<a href="page2.html?x=123" 
onclick="location.replace(this.href); return false">Next</a>
```

to go forward while replacing the link in the history array