# Back Button History: Skipping Page After POST

Tags: asp.net, back-button

[Move backward through history skipping the same page with different query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220211/move-backward-through-history-skipping-the-same-page-with-different-query-string)

The above is *similar* to my question, but I'll be more specific as mine concerns POSTs:

Scenario:
User is on Product Listing page.  (**Shorts.aspx**)
User picks a product and navigates to product detail page (**Best-Cargo-Shorts.aspx**)
User clicks add to cart which performs postback (POST) of form to same page.  (**Best-Cargo-Shorts.aspx**)  -- this now shows Details page again, but with an Added TO Cart message at the top.

Current Behavior:
After the Add TO Cart form post; when the user clicks the Back button they navigate back to the "pre-post" version of the same page.

Desire:
When a user clicks the BACK button, I'd like it to go to **Shorts.aspx**, NOT **Best-Cargo-Shorts.aspx**, effectively Skipping the "pre-POST" page, or more accurately NOT STORING the 2nd POSTed page (Best-Cargo-Shorts.aspx).

Furthermore, I always want to avoid that "Page Content Expired" message.  I just never want the POSTed version of the page in history.  In this way, the following could also be true.

**Shorts.aspx** > **Best-Cargo-Shorts.aspx** > **Best-Cargo-Shorts.aspx** [POST] > **Cart.aspx**

If on cart and BACK button is pressed, I want the browser to navigate to **Best-Cargo-Shorts.aspx** (without the POST).

Is this possible with C#?  Furthermore, is there a non-javascript solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Praise you!  Not enough people out there care if their site works in the absence of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

One common way of handling this is the [Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

In essence, the target of a POST request **always** responds with a 303 See Other (if HTTP 1.1) or 302 Moved Temporarily (if HTTP 1.0) status code redirecting the request as a GET, and usually eliminating the expired POST page from history.  Potential downsides include the form parameters possibly remaining attached to the GET as a query string, and I've no clue how well it would (or wouldn't) integrate with ASP.Net Forms, MVC, or other web frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should be using the post-redirect-get pattern, i.e. after the user adds the item to the card using POST, redirect him to Best-Cargo-Shorts.aspx with 302.
Now to your question, I would use Ajax for the post. I cannot think of a cross-browser way to achieve the desired behaviour using only server side code.