# Use Javascript history.go() to the real "previous" page

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

Assuming we have a history like this:

```
 - Home
 - Page 1
 - Page 2
```

JS `history.go(-1)` works well to go to Page 1... but what if our current history is

```
 - Home
 - Page 1
 - Page 2
 - Page 2 (2nd time)
 - Page 2 (3rd time)
 - ...
 - Page 2 (nth time)
```

How can we use `JavaScript` history object to go back to **Page 1**?

Comment: Use some `jQuery` history `plugin` like http://www.overset.com/2008/06/18/jquery-history-plugin/

Comment: What causes the same page to be saved in the history multiple times in a row? Hash in the url?

Comment: It's a JavaScript limit that you can't read the real history. So basicly you can't determine if the previous page is the same as the current. You can only go back using an integer or as @Juhana said, using a trick with hashes.

Comment: Users can "save and new"... this cause the POST of some data and the GET of the same page. Don't know why [some?] browser save again the page on the history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for this method is `history.go(number|URL)` from [(w3school)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp). So you can use a string parameter instead of number, and if (in some manner) you know which was the url for page2 you can use it.

```
history.go("http://localhost/page2");
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I'll try to use the url helper (I'm on Asp.net MVC) to build that URL based on the parameters i have on the page. Will post the results.

Comment: Or maybe you can do like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220211/move-backward-through-history-skipping-the-same-page-with-different-query-string?rq=1)

Comment: >Will post the results.

 I never did

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that would do a +1 to a property of an object, you could then use this value to go back the right amount of steps

```
var History = {

    steps : 0

}

somenewpagelink.onclick = function() {

    History.steps = (parseInt(History.steps)+1);

}
```

Then if you want to go back to page 1, simple create another function:

```
function goBack() {

    History.go(-History.steps);
    History.steps = 0;

}
```

When you go back the steps will be reset so when you browse further in your site, it won't go back to many steps.

I do think using jQuery is a good solution but not for small things that can easily be solved with raw Javascript, it will only slow your site down if using jQuery for 1 function.

Furthermore you could add a switch in there that if when you click back to actually go back from page 3 to page 1, you could make it reverse too.

```
function goBack(r) {

    if (r)
        history.go(History.steps);
    else 
        history.go(-History.steps);
        History.steps = 0;

}
```

Ofcourse this function would require the tweaking needed to reach the desired effect and be completely flawless, but for the simple implementation you could go with this.

Answer (score 0):

when page is loaded,record now history.length in a js object.
when you want back to page1 ,history.go(record-history.length-1)。
I test it work well.but i dont know whether there will be something unsafe or not.